# How do I update .zshrc

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, zsh

I need to add the following to my .zshrc file to enable connectivity between Airflow and Snowflake (MacOS Monterey 12.0.1).

`export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`

However, when I `open -t .zshrc` the file is locked and I can only save changes to a duplicate. I am sure I am missing something obvious but this is holding me back. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: assumeing your on a mac?

Comment: @JoshBeauregard yes - MacOS Monterey 12.0.1

Comment: I don't know what `open -t` does, but assuming that you have write permission to the file, what happens if you try to edit it with, i.e., `nano .zshrc` or `vi .zshrc`? The error message _is locked_ looks to me as if some process has a lock on it. This could perhaps happen if you do some nasty things in your .zshrc, such as opening an interactive shell. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22259/how-to-check-whats-locking-a-file) for finding the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that somehow you don't have the right permissions to edit your own .zshrc file.

Some script must have changed it while you were running sudo or something.

Te reset your .zshrc file, to its default state, run these two commands one after the other.

```sh
sudo chown $USER:$USER .zshrc
sudo chmod 644 .zshrc
```

Note: `sudo` will ask for your mac users password

Comment: thanks for this - getting the message `chown: dave: illegal group name`

Comment: `$USER` is unlikely to be a valid group name (the part following `:`). What does `ls -l .zshrc` show?

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  446 Nov 17 11:58 .zshrc` should I be using $USER:$staff instead?